# Create a user generated function in R which creates a new column of dates based on values from other columns

Tags: r, function, date, tidyverse

Let's say these are the first few columns of my dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Year = rep(2020, times = 5),
             Month = seq(1:5),
             DayOfMonth = seq(1:5),
             DayOfWeek = seq(1:5))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
   Year Month DayOfMonth DayOfWeek
  <dbl> <int>      <int>     <int>
1  2020     1          1         1
2  2020     2          2         2
3  2020     3          3         3
4  2020     4          4         4
5  2020     5          5         5
```

At the moment the date is split into different columns as above. I would like to create a function that takes the value from each relevant column for each row in the dataset and adds a new column which combines those values into a `yyyy/mm/dd` format.

For example, I want the first row to have a corresponding value in a new "Date" column to be `2020/01/01` (same as 1 January 2020)

Since I'm new to R I don't have a great understanding of making functions myself so I'm struggling to find a starting point. Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Year = rep(2020, times = 5),
             Month = seq(1:5),
             DayOfMonth = seq(1:5),
             DayOfWeek = seq(1:5))


out <-  apply(df, MARGIN = 1, paste, collapse="/")

[1] "2020/1/1/1" "2020/2/2/2" "2020/3/3/3" "2020/4/4/4" "2020/5/5/5"
```

`apply` with `margin = 1` goes through each row and uses the `paste` function collapsing the row vector and places a "/" instead

Edit: whats up with the "DayOfWeek" maybe that should be removed, or just run `apply(df[,1:3], MARGIN = 1, paste,collapse="/")`

```
out <-  apply(df[,1:3], MARGIN = 1, paste,collapse="/")
test <- as.Date(out)

test
[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-02-02" "2020-03-03" "2020-04-04" "2020-05-05"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the output of your function isn't in the yyyy/mm/dd format. I don't want the DayOfWeek column to be appended to the end because that isn't a date I can use.

Comment: updated my answer, but i think, maybe you also need to validate the dates?

Comment: Thanks, the edit helps. I renamed your "test" to "Date" and added it to df with this `df %>% mutate(Date)`.